# Al poner double siempre viene con dos decimales aunque no lo necesite

Tags: java, double

```
`Scanner scanner=new Scanner(System.in);
double num = scanner.nextDouble ();
System.out.println("Este es el número double introducido: "+num);`
```

Si lo ejecutara y cuando pida el número introduzca "2" entonces terminara saliendo al final 2.00
Yo quiero que solo aparezca "2", en el caso de que no haya decimales.
Si introdujese "2.52" no quiero que aparezca ni "2" ni "3", porque redondeando si podra hacerlo.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Si solo necesitas la parte entera, ¿para que utlizar variables tipo double?

En cualquier caso, puedes utilizar el método [printf()](http://puntocomnoesunlenguaje.blogspot.com/2012/08/java-printf.html), para imprimir con formato.

Ejemplo:

```
Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
double num = scanner.nextDouble ();
System.out.printf("Este es el número double introducido: %.0f",num);
```

**Output:**

```
Este es el número double introducido: 1
```

**Actualización**

Mostrar solo el numero de la parte entera en un caso, o mostrar tambien la parte decimal en otro caso, tu ejemplo quedaría de la siguiente manera:

```
Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
double num = scanner.nextDouble();
    
if(num % 1 == 0) {
    System.out.println("Este es el número double introducido: " + (int)num);
}else {
    System.out.printf("Este es el número double introducido: %.2f", num);
}
```

**Output**

```
2,22
Este es el número double introducido: 2,22

2
Este es el número double introducido: 2
```

Comment: Quiero dar la posibilidad de que pongan decimales, pero que en caso de no haber no aparezca

Comment: @sonicmastera he actualizado mi respuesta con lo que necesitas.

Comment: Ni siquiera había pensado en usar un condicional, muchas gracias por la ayuda.